# AWS - How to obtain Billing Monthly Forecast programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-billing

I'm just wondering if it is currently possible to obtain the billing monthly forecast amount using either an SDK or the API.

Looking at the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/operations.html) it doesn't seem possible. Although I haven't delved into the [Cost Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-explorer-api.html) API too much, I was wondering if anyone else has been able to obtain this data point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `GetCostAndUsage` method in  [AWS Billing and Cost Management API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html) which returns the cost and usage metrics. This method also accepts the `TimePeriod` which return the results as per given time frame. Although I didn't test it but you can try to pass future dates in it maybe it will return forecast results. Give it a try

```
{
  "TimePeriod": {
    "Start":"2018-06-01",
    "End": "2018-06-30"
  },
  "Granularity": "MONTHLY",
  "Filter": {      
    "Dimensions": {
      "Key": "SERVICE",
      "Values": [
        "Amazon Simple Storage Service"
      ]
    }
  },
  "GroupBy":[
    {
      "Type":"DIMENSION",
      "Key":"SERVICE"
    },
    {
      "Type":"TAG",
      "Key":"Environment"
    }
  ],
   "Metrics":["BlendedCost", "UnblendedCost", "UsageQuantity"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I found this is also in the aws cli as `aws ce get-cost-and-usage` which returns an `Estimated: true|false` field.